# Are there any "brand" museums in Los Angeles?

Tags: sightseeing, factoids, museums, los-angeles

Atlanta has the Coca Cola museum, Munich has the BMW museum, in Maranello there is the Ferrari museum. Similarly, are there any "brand" museums in LA or its neighborhoods? I know these museums are quite popular in Europe, but haven't seen anything in LA yet.

Comment: What do you mean by brand museum?

Comment: Coca Cola in Atlanta, BMW museum in Munich, Ferrari in Maranello, etc.

Comment: McDonald's Museum in San Bernardino

Comment: Is San Bernardino considered part of LA's neighborhoods?

Comment: I guess yes if it worth 2h driving @CGCampbell

Comment: I must say I was surprised there is nothing listed (to Google) resembling an kind of Movie Studio museums dedicated to specific studios. Maybe they are there, just not very well advertised. If LA (Hollywood) _makes_ anything, it's cinema.

Answer (score 10):

Okay, so I've gone through several Wikipedia pages for southern California...

- McDonald's Museum (also Juan Pollo) in San Bernardino
- Fender Museum of Music and the Arts in Corona (I assume there are some Fender instruments)
- Wells Fargo History Museum (Los Angeles and another one in San Diego)
- Lawrence Welk Museum in Escondido

Related, if you like cars:

- Nethercutt Collection in Sylmar
- Petersen Museum in Los Angeles (Wilshire)

plus others

Comment: Did they ever do anything with the Taco Bell they shipped to Irvine? http://www.lamag.com/askchris/the-first-taco-bell-will-be-saved/

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you had in mind, exactly, but the oldest remaining [Bob's Big Boy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob%27s_Big_Boy) restaurant in Burbank has near-museum status, plus, you know... food.

Answer (score 1):

The [Universal Studios](http://www.universalstudioshollywood.com/) tour? [Disneyland](https://disneyland.disney.go.com/)? (There are other entertainment industry museums, too.)